# Angular delete obj data from array (issue with method)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I have some data in my Angular app.

Here is the data:

In app.component.ts I have:

```
myarr = [
    {
        name: 'mark',
        address: 'something'
    },
    {
        name: 'paul',
        address: 'somethingelse'
    },

];
```

Then I have the method.

```
deleteFromArray(index) {
    delete this.myarr[index];
}
```

In my app.component.html I got:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of myarr; let i = index">
      <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.address }}</td>
      <td>
        <button (click)="deleteFromArray(i)">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The issue I'm having with the delete method is that it's returning:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

This happens when I delete an item.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could instead use `splice()` to modify an array in place: `this.myarr.splice(index, 1)` - this removes one element at position `index`. `delete` on the other hand is used to remove specific properties of an object. Eg. `delete this.myarr[index].address`. This will remove the `address` property of the object in position `index`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64892892/10094636

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      name = 'Angular';
      myarr = [
        {
          name: 'mark',
          address: 'something'
        },
        {
          name: 'paul',
          address: 'somethingelse'
        },
    
      ];
      deleteFromArray(key) {
        let index = this.myarr.findIndex(d => d === key); 
        this.myarr.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(this.myarr)
      }
    }
```

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9sif72?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.myarr.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: For some reason with splice it's not deleting the selected item I clicked on but the last one on the list

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with the `Array.filter` function like this:

```
deleteFromArray(idx: number) {
   this.myarr = this.myarr.filter((element, index) => index !== idx);
}
```

You could also filter the collection by any property, not only index